# Real height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-constraint

I am trying to retrieve the real height in Flutter. I tried different options:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio
```

or

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.height
```

I add these 2 lines in a new Flutter app (from scratch, just the new counter app screen that flutter creates)

I also tried to use a global key, and it does not work (meaning by that that I get the same result). I am testing it in a Samsung a10, which, according to wikipedia, has a `720 x 1520 pixels`. The width I have no problem in calculating it, but the height, is always giving me `1424.0`. Why I am not getting the full height? Is happening me with more phone models.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/physicalSize.html) for the `physicalSize` property:

> This value does not take into account any on-screen keyboards or other system UI. The [padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/padding.html) and [viewInsets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/viewInsets.html) properties provide information about how much of each side of the view may be obscured by system UI.

Comment: `MediaQuery.of(context).padding * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio` (on Samsung a10, to go on with the example) is 54, and `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` is zero, so still I have some pixels that I don't know where they are...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this utility class it gives me the right result

```
class ScreenUtil {
  static ScreenUtil instance = new ScreenUtil();

  int width;
  int height;
  bool allowFontScaling;

  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double _screenWidth;
  static double _screenHeight;
  static double _screenHeightNoPadding;
  static double _pixelRatio;
  static double _statusBarHeight;
  static double _bottomBarHeight;
  static double _textScaleFactor;
  static Orientation _orientation;

  ScreenUtil({
    this.width = 1080,
    this.height = 1920,
    this.allowFontScaling = false,
  });

  static ScreenUtil getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _mediaQueryData = mediaQuery;
    _pixelRatio = mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio;
    _screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;
    _screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height;
    _statusBarHeight = mediaQuery.padding.top;
    _bottomBarHeight = mediaQuery.padding.bottom;
    _textScaleFactor = mediaQuery.textScaleFactor;
    _orientation = mediaQuery.orientation;
    _screenHeightNoPadding =
        mediaQuery.size.height - _statusBarHeight - _bottomBarHeight;
  }

  static MediaQueryData get mediaQueryData => _mediaQueryData;

  static double get textScaleFactory => _textScaleFactor;

  static double get pixelRatio => _pixelRatio;

  static Orientation get orientation => _orientation;

  static double get screenWidth => _screenWidth;

  static double get screenHeight => _screenHeight;

  static double get screenWidthPx => _screenWidth * _pixelRatio;

  static double get screenHeightPx => _screenHeight * _pixelRatio;

  static double get screenHeightNoPadding => _screenHeightNoPadding;

  static double get statusBarHeight => _statusBarHeight * _pixelRatio;

  static double get bottomBarHeight => _bottomBarHeight * _pixelRatio;

  get scaleWidth => _screenWidth / instance.width;

  get scaleHeight => _screenHeight / instance.height;

  setWidth(int width) => width * scaleWidth;

  setHeight(int height) => height * scaleHeight;

  setSp(int fontSize) => allowFontScaling
      ? setWidth(fontSize)
      : setWidth(fontSize) / _textScaleFactor;



}
```

in your build method first call

ScreenUtil().init(context);

then you can call `ScreenUtil.screenHeight`

Comment: Exactly same result, `1424.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android MethodChannel:

```
val windowMetrics = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
val height = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
```